# JBossAS [6.0.0.Final " how to read resources from deployment jar]

Tags: java, jboss

I had an Java EE application that uses Jboss as application server. I had  some xml files under following directory.

/src/main/resources/com/mapping/

When I access project via Junit Test,, I can read xml files using

```
        in = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/com/mapping/file.xml");
```

When I add project as  deployment to Jboss, my resources are exported inside Project.jar under "com/mapping".

Now I am trying to read xml files via following method

```
in = new FileInputStream("com/mapping/file.xml");
```

But I am getting FileNotFoundException.How can I read resources inside JBoss deployment jar.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root directory is different when your are running your unit tests and when you are running from the jar. Furthermore, a resource contained within a JAR file cannot be read using a FileInputStream.

Try using:

```
InputStream inputStream =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/mapping/file.xml");
```

This should work in both cases.